# Tabu package with lengthy line in multi row

Tags: tables, tabu

I'm using tabu package to create a table. With the tabu package, I can specify the width of a table so that lengthy lines are wrapped into the column. 
However, it seems like that the lengthy line in multirow is not propery processed to fit into a column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu} to \linewidth{|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|}

\toprule
x & y & z & w \\
\tabucline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{aaaaa aaaaaaa}  & b & c & d \\
& b & c & dddd sssss \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabu}  
\end{document}
```

How to make the lengthy line in a multi-row column to fit into the column widht?

Comment: if you have recent version of `multirow` packages just replace `*` with `=`. if not, than instead `*` write width of column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `=` instead of `*` in the multirow declaration:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu} to \linewidth{|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|}

\toprule
x & y & z & w \\
\tabucline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{=}{aaaaa aaaaaaa}  & b & c & d \\
& b & c & dddd sssss \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have an error with '=' option.

Comment: Perhaps your multirow is too old. Check the documentation if it mentions =.

Comment: Upgrading to texlive 2016 and running `tlmgr update multirow` solved the error.